# Can I enable Firefox to present the expired client certificate for establishing mutual TLS (mtls)?

Tags: firefox, mozilla, client-certificates, mutual-authentication, mtls

Is there a way Firefox browser can present the expired client certificate for establishing the mutual TLS? At the moment, its not picking up the expired client certificate for presenting it to the server while establishing the MTLS connection. I know its not recommended, however I wanted to test it out for one of the exceptional scenario.

Comment: [Firefox 90+ should pick up system certificates](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2021/07/28/making-client-certificates-available-by-default-in-firefox-90/), have you tried a manual import via `Settings/Privacy and security/Certificates/Show certificates`?

Comment: its MTLS flow, so I can't do manually